# Cannot Load C++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, .net-3.5, dll, crash

[>My previous thread<](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734140/c-crash-when-loading-c-dll)

I created this one,because I installed WinXP on VMBox and I cannot get it working again.

This time I created an OnLoad Event on my form

```
        if (LoadLibrary("blowfish.dll") == 0)
        {
            Misc.LogToFile("Could not load dll", true);
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

Runs fine on my PC,but on VMBox LoadLibrary returns 0.

Some users mentioned that the problem would be in mixing older NET Framework(2.0) with dlls made on newest MS Visual studio(2008 SP1) so I took action and now the program properties it's set to work with NET 3.5

On the VMBox I have NET 2.0,but this is not the problem - the program itself runs fine.I also have C++ Redistributable(2005,2005 SP1 and 2008).

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To further trouble should you could call

```
Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
```

which should give you an error code.

Is it possible that you deployed a debug version of your native dll which also requires a debug version of MSVCR90**D**.DLL? You should have distributed the release version because the debug version requires a different set of dlls to be present on the target system.

It obviously works on your development machine because all debug versions of the required libraries come with Visual Studio.

This is how you would get the message belonging to an error code:

```
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
private static extern int FormatMessage(int dwFlags,
    IntPtr lpSource, int dwMessageId, int dwLanguageId,
    out string lpBuffer, int nSize, IntPtr pArguments);

public static string GetErrorMessage(int errorCode)
{
    const int FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER = 0x00000100;
    const int FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS = 0x00000200;
    const int FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM = 0x00001000;

    string lpMsgBuf;
    int dwFlags = FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER
        | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_IGNORE_INSERTS;

    int retVal = FormatMessage(dwFlags, IntPtr.Zero, errorCode, 0,
                                out lpMsgBuf, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (0 == retVal)
    {
        return null;
    }
    return lpMsgBuf;
}
```

Comment: As String I get "This application has failed to start because its application configuration is incorrect".The error code is 14001.

Please tell me how to fix the application configuration of the dll?

In the DLL project folder I have two filders - Blowfish and Debug.The dll is from the Debug folder.

Comment: Can you try the release build?

Comment: I didn't know the difference between debug and release build and I didn't know how to make it compile the release build,but now,thanks to you - I do! Millions of thanks buddy!

Comment: The FormatMessage declaration should be fixed for 64-bit systems, as I believe lpSource and Arguments are pointers, not ints.

Comment: @SimonMourier: Absolutely correct, I fixed the declaration.

Answer (score 1):

Call GetLastError after LoadLibrary, check the error code value here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681381.aspx
and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It could be that the dll's location is on the path in one environment and not in the other.  It could also be permissions in one environment are not the same as the other.

Comment: Check my previous thread,the hyper link is the first line!
I don't need LoadLibrary,I use external functions.I just set that code to make sure the problem is in the dll.

Answer (score 0):

Try running [dependency walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on the DLL - see if any modules are missing.

Comment: If a dll is missing which gets loaded dynamically by any of the libraries in the dependency tree you will not be able to track that with dependency walker. So a missing library might still be the reason.

Comment: You're right, divo. However, Dependency Walker (newer versions) has a profiling mode where it actually can help in tracking down these dynamically loaded modules.