# Translate COM error codes in C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, com, error-handling

In C, Pascal, and C++ it is possible to use the FormatMessage function to retrieve a "friendly" error message that corresponds to a COM HRESULT error code. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735346/cannot-load-c-dll-in-c) contains sample code that demonstrates the C++ approach. Of course it would be possible to build a managed C++ assembly to perform this function for C# and VB.NET code, but I'm wondering: is there a way to translate COM error codes using the .NET system libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

FormatMessage is already used internally by Win32Exception.  For example:

```
using System;

class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var ex = new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception(unchecked((int)0x80004005));
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Output: Unspecified error

Be sure to avoid bypassing the normal HRESULT checking that's done by the CLR in its COM interop layer.  It uses IErrorInfo to get rich error text from the COM server.  That gets you the 'real' error message rather the generic one.

Answer (score 2):

[Marshal.GetExceptionForHR();](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t8t3ykxc.aspx)

Don't overlook the link on that page which takes you to [How to: Map HRESULTs and Exceptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9ztbc5s1.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't look this this will provide the descriptive message that you can get from FormatMessage(). For example, the Message property of the Exception created from E_FAIL using GetExceptionForHR() simply says, "Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component"

Comment: Well, E_FAIL is not really a good HRESULT; it is basically a generic error message. From WinError.h: `// MessageText: Unspecified error`. Passing E_FAIL to FormatMessage yields "Unspecified error".

Comment: Try another HRESULT, and you get a better exception: `unchecked { System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHR((int)0x80070005L); }` yields `Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))`

Comment: Also, I actually do get the correct text from FormatMessage in the resulting COMException from the `GetExceptionForHR` method: "Unspecified error (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80000008)". Check for yourself: `unchecked { var e = System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetExceptionForHR((int)0x80000008L); Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }`.